# How to pass multiple select data with TagHelpers in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, html-select, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

My problem is: I am unable to pass array data from the view (HTML-select component multiple in mode) to the controller where there is a one-to-many relationship.

I tried to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` for the view.

Please see the MVC design (I simplified it):

Model

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }        
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductCategory")]
    public int Categoryid { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory{ get; set; }
}

public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@model ProjectCategory

<form method="post">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 pt-3">
                <label asp-for="Name"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 pt-3">
                <label asp-for="Products"></label><br/>      
                <select id="Products" asp-for="Accounts" class="form-control" multiple>
                     <option value="">Please select products...</option>       
                     

                   @{
                        Context c = new Context();
                        var products = c.Products.ToList();
                    }

                     @foreach(var r in products){<option value="@r.id">@r.Name</option>}
                 </select>
                 <span asp-validation-for="Products" class="text-danger"></span>   
            </div> 
            <div class="col-12" >
                 <br/> <button type="submit"> Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
// some js code to handle multiple select.. (selectize.js used)
</script>
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(ProductCategory productcategory)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(productcategory);

    // Problem is right here.
    // in debug mode I see, productcategory.Products Count : 0 
    // I could not pass Products from the view to controller
    Context c = new Context();
    c.ProductCategories.Add(productcategory);
    c.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I searched, I saw examples for passing multiple select items to controller but those examples are just with an array, there was no model like this one-to-many, passing model object like my example.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your select, the option field value is `id`, hence you should expect a list of `Product.id`.

Follow the steps below;

1. Make a view model where we will bind the Name and Id list.

```
public class ProductCategoryCreateViewModel {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public List<int> ProductIds {get;set;}
}
```

2. Use the code below for controller, see comments.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
// bind the form data to the view model
public IActionResult Create(ProductCategoryCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      return RedirectToAction("Create");
   
   Context c = new Context();

   // make a new ProductCategory using the ViewModel
   ProductCategory newCategory = new ProductCategory();

   // assign name to new category
   newCategory.Name = viewModel.Name;

   // save the category first so it will generate a new category id
   c.ProductCategories.Add(newCategory);
   c.SaveChanges();
   
   // loop through all product ids selected, and update them with the newcategoryid
   foreach(var id in viewModel.ProductIds){

      // load the product
      var updateProduct = c.Products.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.id == id);

      if(updateProduct != null){

         // if product is found, update the category id
         updateProduct.Categoryid = newCategory.id;
         c.SaveChanges();
      }
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

3. Add `name="ProductIds"` to select tag. Remove `for` attribute.

```
<select name="ProductIds" id="Products" class="form-control" multiple>
   ...        
</select>
```

Comment: I think I understand your approach. I should create a ViewModel. But know how to pass an array as a parameter from the View (such as List<int> ProductIds) here? Could you please add View to your answer?

Comment: @AliCAKIL oops my bad. I updated my answer, need to add name to select tag

Comment: @AliCAKIL were u able to get it working?

Comment: Yes, it worked. But I added @for loop to fill the select tag. Otherwise it appears empty. Thanks! I marked it

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a `List<int>` you can use a simpler way:

1- give a name property to select like:

```
<select name="BayiIdListesi" multiple>
```

2- after that you should rearrange your action like:

```
public IActionResult BayiTopluEmailGonder(List<int> BayiIdListesi)
```

or better:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> BayiTopluEmailGonder(List<int> BayiIdListesi)
```

Note: The tricky part is using same value (BayiIdListesi) for both select's name property and actions parameters name.